# Facebook page feed subscription and page access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

I have created one question today but I still have some problems with subscriptions. I can't get page feed in real-time api. I'm doing this steps below.

1) I have created application.
2) I have created page.
3) I have attached page to application in settings page.
4) I have enabled webhook product and enabled callback url for Page object, then I have subscribed to feed field.
5) I have been adding new posts to my page.

And I have no signal on my webpage with callback url. Someone before told me that I should specify page access token, but, where I can specify page access token to subscription?

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you subscribe your app for updates of your specific page as well? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/

Comment: I think I did, this is a response from GET Request on subscribed apps:

{
  "data": [
    {
      "link": "http://phpcallbackurl.herokuapp.com/",
      "name": "testHubMarket",
      "id": "329234930830448"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: _“And I have no signal on my webpage with callback url”_ - so what exactly does that mean? There is no direct connection between your callback URL and any website ... your callback URL just receives the data Facebook sends. If you want that data to be visible on your website, then you need to facilitate that yourself. // Have you checked your server log files to see if any POST requests for your callback URL where received?

Comment: I have created [link](http://arcane-beach-25011.herokuapp.com/) this application before, this link had been written in my callback. There was no requests, no data on website. Application should print request object on website. I can get data with user likes here but I can't get feed from page.
 @Edit:
Something weird just happen, now I can get feed data from my facebook page but I don't know how I did it.

Comment: Probably Graph API my application to subscribed apps, I don't know. Thanks for help again :).